# When to use HorizontalListView vs. a HorizonalScrollView? Performance?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view

I've been using this [custom android view](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) for having a horizontal listview in my application. But lately I've been goofing around with views and found out I could have the same element using a `HorizonalScrollView` which is a native android layout.
Now my question is this, since `HorizotalListView` is an adaptation of the regular `ListView` and therefore can use the `convertView` feature, is it faster to use `HorizontalScrollView` or should I continue to use the `HorizontalListView`?
Here is how I plan to use the `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
public class AndTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Context c = this;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        int max = 20;
        ImageView img;
        TextView tv;
        for(int i = 0;i<max;i++){
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            View v = li.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setId(i);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            img.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Item clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText("Item: "+img.getId());
            ll.addView(v);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: What results did you get from testing it?

Comment: Since you have written at least one version, if not both, why not use the built-in tools to compare how faster each version performs? [Activity Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html)

Comment: @AndrewMorton What do you mean? I got the result I wanted!

Comment: List provides many additional services: item reuse, selection/long tap processing, relatively painless binding to data collections... They're for different purposes.

Comment: @Sam Never used the tool. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Since my use is relatively simple, my question is subjected to the responsiveness of the techniques.

Comment: @walker Which method was more responsive when you compared them yourself by actually trying them?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well, I guess they perform pretty much the same to my eye. Though the HorizonalListView seems slightly smoother but I'm not sure.